# How to Add Marker in osmdroid?

Tags: android, maps, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am working on OpenStreetMap. I can add this map and get the current position. But, I can't set a mark my position. I use drawable file but I can't see this mark.

This my Android source:

```
            map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
            map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
            map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
            IMapController mapController = map.getController();
            mapController.setZoom(16);

            GeoPoint  currentLocation = new GeoPoint(lat,lon);
            mapController.setCenter(currentLocation);


            OverlayItem myLocationOverlayItem = new OverlayItem("Here", "Current Position", currentLocation);
            Drawable marker = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplication(), R.drawable.markerosm);
            myLocationOverlayItem.setMarker(marker);
```

markerosm.xml file this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <gradient
        android:endColor="#DDBBBBBB"
        android:startColor="#DD777777"
        android:angle="90" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
</shape>
```

I don't take an error but I can't see. How solve this problem?

Comment: This may solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719105/how-to-add-more-marker-in-osm-map-in-android

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(20.5992, 72.9342);
Marker startMarker = new Marker(mapView);
startMarker.setPosition(startPoint);
startMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
mapView.getOverlays().add(startMarker);
```

Comment: I find this and it's working. But we don't forget, we must use osmbonus packet.